# get video name AlAssetLibrary

Tags: ios, xcode, video, alassetslibrary

I want to get video names that i am playing from gallery in MPMoviePlayer, I have searched a lot about getting videos name that are played from gallery, but i always get only path, can i get name of video?what should i do? any idea? i saw examples for video path only like this

```
ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{
"com.apple.quicktime-movie" = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=336068EA-C1B1-481C-82DA-F2419561A91A&ext=MOV";
```

In this path what will be the video name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [anAssetItem defaultRepresentation];
NSString *fileName = [assetRep filename];
```

Returns a string representing the filename of the representation on disk.

**Note:**
For representations synced from iTunes, this will be the filename of the representation on the host.

Comment: This working me when I record a new video. But if I choose an existing video I get allways null for file name.